# Can I calculate r correlation for catigorical and numerical value?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have been reading a paper and I have found a table that felt very strange for me. The researchers have calculated r value and related it to a categorical factor. From my knowledge r is a function of correlation between two numerical variables.

Any ideas 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BguRJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to assess the association between a continuous variable and a dichotomous variable (e.g. gender), you would typically use the point-biserial correlation

However, pearson and point-biserial are mathematically equivalent and will give you the same correlation value. So technically their values are correct, just that their naming might be a bit misleading/confusing